# Can we get any result or feedback when launched a link in UIWebview within an ipad application

Tags: ios, ipad, url, uiwebview, safari

I developed an ipad app where in i have a situation where the user taps a button which redirects to a login page (UIWebView),The user enters his credentials and web page hits a server where the validation takes place and the browser is returned a feed back string (authorization).

Question:
Is there a provision to know the feedback string/data by the application? According to my knowledge as soon as a webView is launched our application has no info about the happenings on Webview.

I don't want to implement services in my application since the service provider says that the webpage redirects the user to app upon successful login.Which may be possible on a desktop,but in ipad application can the bowser/Webview redirect back to the application upon login and more ever i need the feedback string in my application.Can some one suggest how could i implement the same.Please correct me if i am going wrong...

TNQ

Answer (score 0):

You can call Objective-C methods from UIWebView. This you can do by trapping your custom urls in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method.  More details are [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/).